# Edge Animate Javascript error in event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, adobe-edge

In Adobe Edge 2015 project I have 2 symbols popupbutton1 and popupbutton2 and I'm trying to change opacity of popupbutton2 when mouse is over popupbutton1. But I get an error 
`edge.6.0.0.min.js:155 Javascript error in event handler! Event Type = element`

in `sym.getSymbol("popupbutton2").animate({ 'opacity': 0.4}, 500);`

but the code `sym.getSymbol("popupbutton2").hide()` works well and this
code with opacity changing has worked in previous version of Edge Animate.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has to do with Adobe Edge dropping jQuery from its native API.

See here to add jQuery back into your project and (hopefully) restore functionality: https://jquery.com/download/

Do be aware that jQuery will trump the Edge API if you do so, but I haven't seen a downside to that as yet.

Alternatively, just add the following line to the beginning of your edgeproject.html:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Hope that helps!